# Parameter type cannot be null

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm trying to execute an sp in ef core.

I have defined a data model class for the sp results.  It's been added as a DbSet in the context

```
public class GroupedCountResult
{
    [Required]
    [Column("varchar(100)")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Column("varchar(20)")]
    public string Colour { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

The code for calling the sp is:

```
string OrgCode = "code";
string ProcessDate = new DateTime(2019, 08, 01).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

IEnumerable<GroupedCountResult> counts =  _context.GroupedCountResults
  .FromSql($"usp_get_count_for_org_for_single_date '{OrgCode}', '{ProcessDate}'")
  .AsEnumerable();
```

When it attempts to execute, it tells me that the value **type** cannot be **null**

```
System.ArgumentNullException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.InversePropertyAttributeConvention.ConfigureInverseNavigation(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder, MemberInfo navigationMemberInfo, InternalEntityTypeBuilder targetEntityTypeBuilder, InversePropertyAttribute attribute)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.InversePropertyAttributeConvention.Apply(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder, PropertyInfo navigationPropertyInfo, Type targetClrType, InversePropertyAttribute attribute)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.NavigationAttributeEntityTypeConvention`1.Apply(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnEntityTypeAdded(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.RunVisitor.VisitOnEntityTypeAdded(OnEntityTypeAddedNode node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnEntityTypeAddedNode.Accept(ConventionVisitor visitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionVisitor.Visit(ConventionNode node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionVisitor.VisitConventionScope(ConventionScope node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionScope.Accept(ConventionVisitor visitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionVisitor.Visit(ConventionNode node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionVisitor.VisitConventionScope(ConventionScope node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Run()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalModelBuilder.Entity(TypeIdentity& type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Boolean allowOwned, Boolean throwOnQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalModelBuilder.Entity(Type type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Boolean allowOwned, Boolean throwOnQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.Entity(Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.FindSets(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelCustomizer.FindSets(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<GetModel>b__1()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_2(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSql[TEntity](IQueryable`1 source, FormattableString sql)
   at Ctrack.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in C:\Users\lukem\source\Ctrack.Dashboard\Ctrack.Dashboard\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 31
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
```

I have no idea where to find this type parameter that is null.

Comment: What is the ` InverseProperty` and what is the data model? What is `usp_get_count_for_org_for_single_date`? Share us detail steps which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: The InverseProperty decorator was used in a different class to create a Navigation collection.  `usp_get_count_for_org_for_single_date` is the stored procedure i am trying to execute.  New question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385381/executing-an-sp-in-ef-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been caused by an InverseProperty on a data model object.  Trying to run my query caused the model to be created caused this other class to throw the error.

I've commented it out till i have to fix it.